# i have included only 0 index similarly i have 0 to 8 index and I want to insert this array into PHP sql database

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [RESTAURANT_NAME] => Harikant Restaurant 
    [Food_option] => Pure veg 
    [Latitude] => 28.8235288 
    [Longitude] => 77.1289813 
    [Address] => Khampur,Khampur Village, Delhi, 110036 
    [Restaurant_website] => 
    [Phone_number] => 
  )
)
```

Comment: Please provide more information how you want to insert it to SQL (PDO, Mysqli, Doctrine)? Please format your comment and add some code.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: use a foreach loop, to access each and insert it

Comment: @PatNowak using Mysqli

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

1. use [implode function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to convert array to string or
2. convert the array to json and then store it in to database.

I recommend second option as it very easy to access the data

Answer (score 0):

You can try foreach loop like this

```
foreach($var_array as $var){

   //you can convert this whole 0 index array as string by implode function
   $string  = implode($var);
    // now you can insert this string into any field of table
   $query = insert into table(field) values($string);

  // you can also insert all values separately 

  $query = insert into table(field1,field2,...) 
  values($var['RESTAURANT_NAME'],$var['Food_option'],...)
}
```